# Sending image from C# Server to Java client through TCP socket

Tags: c#, java, image, object, tcp

I have an image in my server which I want to send to my Java client through sockets. In c# I converted to byte array and then tried to send over the socket. But, a byte array in C# is unsigned so I tried to send signed byte array sbyte[] but it cannot be send by `clientSocket.Send()` method. On the java client side, I need to convert the byte array received to an Image object. Here is the exception trace that I get, at `Image image = reader.read(0, param)`.  Please help me with this.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.imageio.IIOException: Bogus marker length
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readImageHeader(Native Method)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readNativeHeader(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.checkTablesOnly(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.gotoImage(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readHeader(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(Unknown Source)
at ServerByteStreamWithoutOIS.main(ServerByteStreamWithoutOIS.java:54)
```

## Here is my C# server code:

```
class Program
{
static void Main(String[] args)
{
Socket sListen = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

// 2. Fill IP
IPAddress IP = IPAddress.Parse("147.174.117.187");
IPEndPoint IPE = new IPEndPoint(IP, 20229);

// 3. binding
sListen.Bind(IPE);

// 4. Monitor
Console.WriteLine("Service is listening ...");
sListen.Listen(2);

// 5. loop to accept client connection requests
while (true)
{
Socket clientSocket;
try
{
clientSocket = sListen.Accept();
}
catch
{
throw;
}


// send the file
byte[] buffer = ReadImageFile("1.jpg");

clientSocket.Send(buffer, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
clientSocket.Close();
Console.WriteLine("Send success!");
}
}


private static byte[] ReadImageFile(String img)
{
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(img);
byte[] buf = new byte[fileInfo.Length];
FileStream fs = new FileStream(img, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
fs.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
fs.Close();
//fileInfo.Delete ();
GC.ReRegisterForFinalize(fileInfo);
GC.ReRegisterForFinalize(fs);
return buf;
}
}
}
```

## Here is my Java client:

```
public class ServerByteStreamWithoutOIS {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
int port = 20229;
Socket sock = null; 
InetAddress addr = null;
addr = InetAddress.getByName("147.174.117.187");    
sock = new Socket(addr, port);
System.out.println("created socket!");
int count = 0;
while(true){
String line = "";
String realLine = "";
BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
byte[] buffer = null;
while((line=bReader.readLine() )!=null){
realLine = realLine + line;
System.out.println(line.getBytes());
}

buffer = realLine.getBytes();

//buffer = (byte[])ois.readObject();

ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);
Iterator<?> readers = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("jpg");

ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) readers.next();
Object source = bis; // File or InputStream, it seems file is OK

ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(source);
//Returns an ImageInputStream that will take its input from the given Object

reader.setInput(iis, true);
ImageReadParam param = reader.getDefaultReadParam();

Image image = reader.read(0, param);
//got an image file

BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
//bufferedImage is the RenderedImage to be written
Graphics2D g2 = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
g2.drawImage(image, null, null);
File imageFile = new File("image.bmp");
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "bmp", imageFile); 

System.out.println(imageFile.getPath());

//Thread.sleep(100);
System.out.println("Done saving");
}
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the error is because you are converting the bytes received in the Java server to a string representation. This can result in an error because a jpg is binary data, and when some binary data can not be converted to a character in a string, some conversion occurs which will result in an error when you use the `getBytes()` function.

If you instead read the bytes from the inputstream using the `read(byte[],int,int])` function, I think you should be alright.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[], int, int)

---

Edit, added a working code example

The "problem" of Java having signed bytes is a non issue. In binary they are the same bits, so when written to a file, the same bits are written since they are still the same order.

I wrote an example of a C# client and a Java server that I got working. I'm sure you can find it of use.

**Server – Java**

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ImageServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8000);
            Socket accept = server.accept();
            InputStream inputStream = accept.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
            int length = readInt(inputStream);
            byte[] buf = new byte[length];
            for (int read = 0; read < length; ) {
                read += stream.read(buf, read, buf.length - read);
            }
            stream.close();

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("image.png");
            fos.write(buf, 0, buf.length);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static int readInt(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        byte[] buf = new byte[4];
        for (int read = 0; read < 4; ) {
            read += inputStream.read(buf, 0, 4);
        }
        return toInt(buf);
    }

    public static int toInt(byte[] b) {
        return (b[0] << 24)
                + ((b[1] & 0xFF) << 16)
                + ((b[2] & 0xFF) << 8)
                + (b[3] & 0xFF);
    }
}
```

**Client – C#**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Test.SendImageClient {
    public class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            if (args.Length == 0) {
                Console.WriteLine("usage: client imagefile");
                return;
            }
            FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(args[0]);

            Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            socket.Connect("localhost", 8000);
            int length = IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder((int)stream.Length);
            socket.Send(BitConverter.GetBytes(length), SocketFlags.None);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
                socket.Send(buffer, 0, read, SocketFlags.None);
            }
            socket.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your method with this code:

`byte[] buffer = new byte[3000];`
`inputStream.read(buffer, 0, 3000);`

Now i get the exception `Not a jpeg file starts with 0x04 0x48` 

i think its because c# sends unsigned byte array and java is treating it like signed byte array. do you know anyway i can send sbyte array to java over socket? 

Thanks

Comment: @mojorisinify: Can you verify if it may be because of endianess? Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92287/sending-a-4-byte-message-header-from-c-sharp-client-to-a-java-server/92983#92983 for an example of how to convert an int to network order. If you set a breakpoint in Visual Studio you can check the first byte in your C# byte array, and verify the first received byte in your Java server.

Comment: Btw, instead of creating a fixed byte array, send the byte array length from your C# client and read that many bytes in your Java server. Use the return value from the read function to know how many bytes have been read, and iterate until you have all your bytes.

Comment: Good news actually, now using the same inputstream.read() it now gets the image from C# but the image is corrupted. Some of the pixels are not right. But for the most part, the image is visible. The error is the same though `Not a jpeg file: starts with 0xd9 0xff`. If it was for endian, the image wouldn't have been saved in java client would it?

Comment: @mojorisinify Sure you can save it, but as you state it is corrupted. You can try to verify it it is because of the byte order (endianess) if you check the bytes received compared to the ones sent, are they the same value?

Comment: I wrote a small test program to see the results.. what I did was 
`byte[] buffer = {23};`
`clientSocket.send(buffer, buffer.length, SocketFlags.None);`

That was in C# and in Java I did this:

`byte[] buffer = new byte[1]`
`inputStream.read(buffer, 0, 1);`

And while printing the buffer[0] value i get the same 23. I guess this is normal.. so no endian issues I hope.

Comment: @mojorisinify: I added an example in my answer that works on my machine. I hope it will work for you as well!

Comment: @mojorisinify: How come you removed this as the accepted answer almost a year after you accepted it?

Comment: accidental consequence. there you go now.

Answer (score 1):

it seems like the bytes being received are not lining up w/the jpeg specification (can't be deserialized properly).  are you sure the file on the server exists and that the c# byte[] is getting filled properly?  maybe try to write the file on the server before sending it through the socket to ensure that you are actually reading a valid jpeg on the server.

Comment: Yes, the file exists on the server and C# byte is filled. I have tested and it actually works in C#. The problem is after you send it to Java client. I think its because I don't know how to send a sbyte over a socket. Java gets the byte which is not signed and thinks as if its a signed byte array.